# Which is the folder of my ftp server in my website?

Tags: ftp

I'm the administrator of a website and I use a cPanel to manage it, and/or Filezilla to upload and download my files.
The thing that I can't understand is which is my root ftp forlder. There is a folder in my home directory that is called public_ftp but the contents of this foder does not appear at my browser when I visit ftp://ftp.mysite.com . There is only a folder called 'pub'. I really can't understand how this works and where to upload my files in order to be visible when I visit ftp://ftp.mysite.com.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: k.  You access your hosting service via CPanel.  See the section there dealing with FTP access?  Notice how the initial directory that you have access to when using FTP is defined when you set up the FTP account?  That means that depending on the username (the account) used when connecting via an FTP client, you could end up in different directories by default.  Try creating an FTP account that drops you into your WWW or Public_HTML directory instead.

Comment: But I don't want to use an ftp client to connect. I just want to type in my browser ftp://ftp.mysite.com and see the files on my ftp folder that I want to be public for the people to download. Sorry if I don't understand something basic here!

Comment: @Zosimas - Using a ftp client and the browser as your ftp client is exactly the same.  So what you want makes no sense.

Comment: Oh I'm sure it does! If you go to [ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/) you will see a list of downloadable files. I'm sure there are somewhere in a folder, aren't they. So which is this f@$%ing folder and what are the permissions of this folder and the files in it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, the folder FTP will default you to is the home folder of the user you use to authenticate. In many cases, this is /home/username

Comment: And wich would be the user if I just type in my browser ftp://ftp.mysite.com ???

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood. I was talking about if you were using FileZilla or FTP or something. For an unathenticated browser, that's going to be anonymous access, and you'll probably want to set it up so there's permissions to access your public_ftp folder. (chmod -R 744 public_ftp). I'm guessing the files will then show up when you browse to it.